# Unable to drop columns from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, drop

I am trying to drop a column from a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Caravan_Dataset.csv')
X = df.drop('Purchase',axis=1)
y = df['Purchase']
```

but it does not work.
I also tried the following one:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Caravan_Dataset.csv')
X = df.drop('Purchase',axis=1,inplace=True)
y = df['Purchase']
```

but it does not work neither. ıt keeps giving an error like Purchase is still on the columns. Any idea about how can I do it?

Comment: Can you clarify what your desired outcome is? If you drop the Purchase column in the second line, then in the third line (y = df...) it won't be available to assign. Are you aiming to get that error?

Answer (score 2):

When `inplace = True` , the data is modified in place, which means it will return nothing and the dataframe is now updated. When `inplace=False`, you will need to assign it to something new.

Change your code from:

```
X = df.drop('Purchase',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

To this:

```
df.drop('Purchase',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Or, alternatively use `inplace=False` (which is the default) and returns a copy of the object, and use:

```
X = df.drop('Purchase',axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign it to `df` like `df = df.drop('column_name',asix=1)`